# Cosa vuol dire "posta" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Un freddo nei capelli m’avvisò che si trattava dell’inizio di una partita d’armi assai seria, chissà quale ne era
>   la **posta**, in quel cono d’aria lassù, che disegnavano i riflettori. Un gioco serio era, con qualche sottinteso abietto, di cui venivo tenuto all’oscuro.

Mi potreste spiegare il significato di "posta" in questo brano? Ho cercato questo vocabolo in alcuni dizionari ma, tra le tantissime accezioni che ho trovato, non riesco a capire a quale corrisponda l'occorrenza in questo testo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il significato di ***posta*** nel passaggio da te citato è quello figurato, cioè di vantaggio o beneficio che poteva derivare dalla vittoria nello scontro armato.

L'accezione di [posta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/posta1/) su Treccani adatta è la seguente:

> 4. Ciò che si pone. In partic.: a. Somma di denaro che si arrischia in un gioco: *stabilire la p.; fare le p.; distribuire le p.; la p. minima
>      è di dieci euro; una p. alta, bassa; qual è la p. in gioco*, o *di
>      gioco?; versare, raddoppiare la p.; in poco tempo ha perso tutta la
>      p.;* analogam., *la p. di una scommessa;* anche, puntata al gioco del
>      lotto. **In senso fig., ciò che si può vincere o perdere in un’impresa
>      di vario genere (anche un bene morale, o la vita stessa)**: *fino a ieri
>      giocavi con la p. della tua vita* (Monelli); *la p. in gioco è molto,
>      troppo alta;* con altro sign., *non stare alla p.*, non mantenere i
>      patti.